# exporting IDML Document to XML

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign, idml

I want to know if there is a way where i can export a document created in InDesign to XML provided a DTD is given, when i tried to do one by selecting export option and format as XML,  i got the below output.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>

<Root />
```

The InDesign document i tried to export is of 250 pages, but the output i got is only two lines first giving XML declaration and the second as root. please let me know how i can export this document in XML format.

Thanks

Comment: That's because you did not *tag* the proper text with any XML tags at all. ID does not magically know by itself what tag should go where. Use "Map Styles to Tags", and/or read [InDesign's Online Help Page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WS372C59DB-BD13-4806-A399-794E754FF37Aa.html) about how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You cant straight away export it to XML, you have to either map or you should have loaded XML earlier into indesign.